# Can the Romanian border be crossed at the Tripoint of the Balkans?

Tags: schengen, borders, romania, hungary, serbia

At the [Tripoint of the Balkans](https://maps.app.goo.gl/tJZhZkECBqurwhCp9?g_st=ic) (Hungary, Romania, Serbia – located near Szeged), there is a border crossing station between Hungary and Serbia (apparently opened a few years ago), yet there doesn't appear to be a Romanian one. The Romanians however built a new road to the Serbian border, where a 'Republic of Serbia - Welcome' sign is located next to the road, and the road briefly turns into a path until it reaches the road from Hungary to Serbia. (C.f. linked satellite imagery and fairly recent StreetView imagery on the Romanian road.)

Given the 'Welcome' sign: Can the Serbian-Romanian border be crossed there by some sort of special arrangement, even though the Romanians do not appear to have a border crossing station there?

Comment: There’s a border police building a bit further down the road on the Romanian side in Beba Veche. Not sure if that’s supposed to be a border crossing post or just a base for police patrolling the area. Too bad we can’t see the sign from the Serbian side, to see if it just says welcome as well, or if it has any instructions (like “report to the office in Beba Veche”), or on the opposite “do not cross here”. But the fact they have this pretty decent road open right to the border would make one think that at least Romania expects it to be used.

Comment: There seems to be some conflict between Hungary and Romania about a border crossing in Beba Veche though, with Romania apparently refusing to open such a crossing. And since it’s a point of entry into the EU on a path used by migrants (and Hungary have built a fence on the neighbouring border), they probably don’t like people just strolling in… your best bet is probably to try to contact the border post in Beba Veche and ask? No number listed on Google Maps though.

Comment: Looks like it’s not an official border crossing point: https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=uriserv:OJ.C_.2018.368.01.0004.01.ENG&toc=OJ:C:2018:368:TOC one wonders what the point of that road and those signs is. One can get a glimpse of the other side of the sign here: https://www.gettyimages.ch/detail/nachrichtenfoto/policemen-patrol-the-border-area-at-triplex-confinium-nachrichtenfoto/846905598?language=fr though it’s difficult to make out what is says.